# Change beamer size after loading a beamertemplate

Tags: beamer, margins, templates, geometry, adjustwidth

I am writing the code for a beamer template. I have two different templates for the `frametitle`, one of them makes the frame a little asymmetric. Hence, I set the `text margin left` and the `text margin right` to be `8ex` and `5ex` respectively. The other one is more symmetric, hence I would like that after `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[second template]` the text in all frames after that is centred.

Of course I can not use `\setbeamersize` inside the body of the document. Using `\newgeometry` moves the entire frame. I do not know how to set `adjustwidth` for all frames.

**HERE A MWE**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=blue!20!black}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{plain}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=2ex,%
      leftskip=.2ex,%
      rightskip=.2ex,%
    ]{frametitle}%%
  \insertframetitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{leftside}{%
\nointerlineskip%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\beamer@leftmargin - 1cm\relax}% 
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
          wd=1cm,%
          sep=2ex,%
          leftskip=.2ex,%
          rightskip=.2ex,%
        ]{example text}%
        \vphantom{F}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
       \smash{%
        \rotatebox[origin=rt]{90}{%
          \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
              wd=\paperheight,%
              sep=2ex,%
              leftskip=.2ex,%
              rightskip=.2ex,%
            ]{frametitle}%
            \insertframetitle
          \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }%
    \vskip-3ex
}
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=8ex, text margin right=3ex}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[leftside]
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    The text here is placed correctly\hfill the right margin is ok
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    The text here is not ok \hfill too close to the right margin\\
    \hspace{-2.5ex}Here it is ok\hfill and the right margin is also ok\hspace{2.5ex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I added the following code in the preamble

```
\usepackage{changepage}
\newlength{\leftshift}
\setlength{\leftshift}{-1.5ex}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\endbeamer@frameslide
  {\end{adjustwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd\beamer@frameslide
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftshift}{-\leftshift}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

changing `\leftshift` whenever the new template is loaded. It works pretty well, despite the fact the inline `frametitle` which is read as the text of the frame (I mean `\begin{frame}{This text is read inside text area}`.  I would love it if someone could fix it.

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text width stays the same and you don't need navigations symbols or other static elements, you might get away by changing the `\hoffset`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=blue!20!black}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{plain}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \hspace*{2.3ex}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=2ex,%
      leftskip=.2ex,%
      rightskip=.2ex,%
    ]{frametitle}%%
  \insertframetitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}[action]{
\hoffset=-3ex
}


\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{leftside}{%
\nointerlineskip%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\beamer@leftmargin - 1cm\relax}% 
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
          wd=1cm,%
          sep=2ex,%
          leftskip=.2ex,%
          rightskip=.2ex,%
        ]{example text}%
        \vphantom{F}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
       \smash{%
        \rotatebox[origin=rt]{90}{%
          \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
              wd=\paperheight,%
              sep=2ex,%
              leftskip=.2ex,%
              rightskip=.2ex,%
            ]{frametitle}%
            \insertframetitle
          \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }%
    \vskip-3ex
}[action]{
\hoffset=0ex
}
\makeatother


\setbeamersize{text margin left=8ex, text margin right=3ex}


\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[leftside]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    The text here is placed correctly\hfill the right margin is ok
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    The text here is not ok \hfill too close to the right margin
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    The text here is not ok \hfill too close to the right margin
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[leftside]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    The text here is placed correctly\hfill the right margin is ok
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, but I may have some page numbers in the `footer` (this is the reason why in my MWE I did not clear the `navigation symbol` template) or the background may be of a different colour. Could you also explain why you moved the `frametitle` of `2.3ex`? Where does this length come from?

Comment: @totallyimmersed9 You could add some hskip to your footline etc, to compensate for the space, or position such elements relative to the page. The `2.3ex` was found with the reliable method of trial and error.

Comment: Well, It is not exactly what I am looking for. I was asking for something more reliable. Thank you.